# Programatically escape / script closing tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this variable which contains a script html code

```
<script>
var script = "<script>console.log('script here')</script>"
</script>
```

how do we programmatically escape the `/` in the  closing tag `</script>` so it will look like the code below

```
<script>
var script = "<script>console.log('script here')<\/script>"
</script>
```

Comment: If you're certain that there's only one occurence of a closing tag in the string then you can use a simple `script.replace('/', '\\/')`. Otherwise, RegEx would be better: `script.replace(/\//g, '\\/')`.

Comment: There can be a code that contains / inside the script tag. This scripts will be programmatically added to HTML. I will be using a loop to insert the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work as you think.

The first fragment of code does not work because the browser finds the `</script>` piece in the string and thinks that it is the closing tag of the script element. It treats the rest of the script and the real `</script>` closing tag as regular text and displays it in the page (except for the `</script>` tag).

This means that only a fragment of your script is parsed, the parser finds a syntax error in it (the string is not closed) and the script does not run.

There is no way to fix this using JavaScript code. It is not a coding problem. It is an HTML problem (kind of) and its only solution is to write the HTML in a way that avoids the issue.

The HTML document contains a closing tag `</script>` inside the body of a `script` element. For normal HTML content (a paragraph, for example) the solution is straight forward: use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to encode `<` and `>`:

```html
<p> This is a paragraph that contains a &lt;p&gt; closing tag</p>
```

You should do it anyway everywhere you want `<` and `>` to represent themselves (to be rendered and not interpreted as tag markers) to produce correct HTML.

This simple solution is not possible in the `<script>` element because the content of the `<script>` element is not parsed by the HTML parser. It only finds the first appearance of the `</script>` closing tag and passes the content to the JavaScript parser. And the JavaScript parser does not understand `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

However, there is a simple solution for your problem. Make sure that the script does not contain the string `</script>` and everything will work without problems.

Usually, this is done either by writing:

```js
var script = "<script>console.log('script here')<\/script>"
```

or by splitting the string in two sub-strings in the middle of the `script` word:

```js
var script = "<script>console.log('script here')</scr" + "ipt>"
```

The first solution looks a little better.

Another, even easier, solution is to not put the JavaScript code into an inline `script` element but keep it in a `.js` file and link that file into the HTML document:

```html
<script src="my-fancy-script.js"></script>
```

The file `my-fancy-script.js` looks like this:

```js
var script = "<script>console.log('script here')</script>"
```

This way, the content of the `my-fancy-script.js` file is passed directly to the JavaScript parser that is not fooled by any appearance of `</script>` in the code.

Comment: the "var script" are dynamically generated. so there could be multiple <script></script> tags. the code is just an example, because I am storing those script tag to a variable, and will programmatically insert them to the HTML page. The app I'm building allows user to add script from their dashboard. The app works like a quiz, in every questions they can embed a tracking scripts or add a custom script that will modify the content of the question.

Comment: the reason why I need to use inline script is that I need to insert the script that has been added from the admin dashboard, it's dynamically created. I will also be using a certain event and trigger the script insertion, that's why I'm storing the <script> tags to a variable.

Comment: The suggestion provided in the answer still apply. The HTML code is not written by hand but generated (it is written by hand elsewhere beforehand). Put `<\/script>` instead of `</script>` in the code that generates the script tag. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

An approach could be:

```
var script = "<script>console.log('script here')</script>";
script = script.replace('</script>', '<\/script>');
```

The same for the opposite:

```
var script = "<script>console.log('script here')<\/script>";
script = script.replace('<\/script>', '</script>');
```

Comment: When it is placed directly in the HTML, your first script fails to parse the same way as the script posted in the question.