# How to escape html tags in text

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like:
`<td><a href="#"><script>document.write("${name}");</script></a></td>`

when the name is equals to for example `</script>test`

then I got errors in console with: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

if name is equls to `<script>asda<script>` then I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

How can I escape those HTML tags and display text as it is ? I want this text to be interpreted as plain text, nothing more but weird situations happens when I put something special under the name.

If the input consists of special characters like for example '[]pol' then everything is fine.

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692123/escape-tags-in-html

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript

Comment: maybe use `innerText` instead of `document.write();`, also `innerHTML` is good (but isn't suggested for security reasons)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext. but if you want use `document.write()` you can search the HTML codes for displaying < or > https://mateam.net/html-escape-characters/ (here you will see a list)

Comment: [Don't use document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) unless you know _exactly_ what you are doing. In which case you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.

Comment: @GrafiCode it does not work. It throws exception before going to the method...

Comment: the problem is `</script>`. As you can see here, https://jsfiddle.net/f6qhtaek/ all combinations work. Here, instead, when string contains `</script>` it fails: https://jsfiddle.net/f6qhtaek/3/  Looks like the only way is to split it, like this `'<' + '/script>'`

Comment: @GrafiCode but if I write method to split text like this, I will get another error but in another place, am I right?

Comment: yes I'm afraid so. I think it's the browser's html parser, it will always fail to escape when encountering `</script>`. Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66192561/string-doesnt-accept-the-close-tag-for-script and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65944545/programatically-escape-script-closing-tag-in-javascript

Comment: @GrafiCode I esacped this characters on backend  and passed in ready, escaped form.

Comment: I think that's the best solution, preprocessing stuff in backend and then passing it to the front-end ready to be used.

Answer (score 1):

`&lt;` ("less than") is the HTML entity for "<", and `&gt;` ("greater than") for ">"

`&lt;script&gt;` = "<script>"

Comment: and I need to replace all special characters with this and it will display proper characters on the page?

Comment: see second comment to your question...